# What are the best tools available for SEO?

Tags: seo

I am Using IISSEO tool that gives a report after analyzing our website. The report also 
contains recommondations to fix the violations in the web site. 
but, my doubt is that fixing 
the bugs is enough task for SEO specialist otherwise does he has any extra functionality?

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on what kind of info you want through those SEO tools. IISEO is great tool in terms of checking technical stuff. If you want to have a stable, high loading speed web site, then yes IISEO is a pretty tool. And if what you mean by SEO is technically focused, most of such tools are the same, meaning you do not need to look other tools.

However, as you may know, SEO is far more than that. SEO is improving the visibility of your web site on the whole internet, finding your targeted visitors and concomitantly improve user experience of your site...

That is why the gold rule in SEO is content. Content is king in that regard. Also, links structure on your site, decent number of in-bound links to your site, and so forth are extremely critical. And that is why web analysts tools like Google analysis tool are vital.

So the answer to your question is yes, that is not enough. Try use tools that focus on different respects of SEO, and most importantly, use the tool of communication, listening to your visitors and keep improving as the suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Seo Panel](http://www.seopanel.in/), an open source SEO tool.